# Blender Dev: Global location to store project properties?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, properties

Is there anything more global than a scene that can contain project-related properties that should be saved to each *.blend file?

Since a single file/project can contain any number of scenes, where would an add-on typically store properties that should only exist in one place?

Looking for something like..

```
bpy.types.SingletonObject.my_properties = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MyProjectData)
```

**Edit:**
For anyone interested in doing this, here are some of the ideas I've found online so far. Except the last one - that one is from me.

- Store properties in Window Manager - AFAIK, this only works if you don't want to save the data to the *.blend file.
- Create an *empty* object and store properties in it. I'm no expert at this, but I believe the empty would need to exist somewhere (a scene). So what happens when the user deletes that scene?
- Create a custom/dummy ID-block and attach properties to it. I don't completely understand this one yet, but looking into it.
- This one is something I thought up and am considering using. It is not as simple as the others, but should allow storing global properties in a single location, as well as saving/loading those properties with the *.blend file:

  1. Store all properties in a custom structure that is attached to BOTH the add-on preferences and the scene data. Will refer to this as `global_props`. So it would be located at `bpy.context.preferences.addons["project"].preferences.global_props` and `bpy.data.scenes[0].global_props`. You would only ever reference the one in the add-on preferences except in the steps below..
  2. Setup a `bpy.app.handlers.load_post` handler. After a file is loaded, use the handler to copy `global_props` from the *scene* to *preferences*.
  3. Setup a `bpy.app.handlers.save_pre` handler. Right before a file is saved, use the handler to copy `global_props` from *preferences* to *scene*.
  4. Anywhere you deal with `global_props`, access and use the preferences version.

     Some notes:

     - It may be possible to only attach `global_props` to the scene right before the file is saved, then delete it after, if you wanted to avoid wasting the memory it would take up. Not sure if this would cause issues or not.
     - Using this setup would allow you to give the user the option to save certain properties locally (*.blend) or globally. It would be very easy to simply avoid transferring some of the data based on certain options. This was a feature I really needed for my export add-on.
     - Let me know if you think of any issues that would stem from using this setup. I'm currently planning to make use of it.

Comment: Some of the add-ons that come with blender like *rigify* assigning some of the properties to the window manager: `bpy.types.WindowManager`... also you can print a complete list of all available types in the console by using pythons `dir()` on `bpy.types`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm surprised Blender doesn't provide a specific type for add-ons to attach global project properties to. There is also this list https://docs.blender.org/api/2.80/bpy.types.html - but wow there are a lot of them.

Comment: Here is a link to another question that is pretty much identical to mine. No real answers, but some helpful bits: https://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=27291 - they seem to suggest that properties attached to the window manager do not get saved to file. However, this was back in 2013, so I'm sure some things have changed. And here is one more: https://blenderartists.org/t/global-property/626010/6 (2014)

Comment: I think you can only assign custom properties to subclasses of `ID` (or `Bone` or `PoseBone`). `BlendData` inherits directly from bpy_struct, so I don't think it is allowed.

Comment: Yeah, tested. nope @Robert I'd use the prefs... that's easy to maintain.

Comment: Yeah, that's essentially how that setup works. Everything is dealt with from the prefs. But add-on prefs don't get saved with blend files. So I am copying parts of the prefs to/from the scene when files are saved/loaded. Whichever parts the user chooses to save locally versus globally. There are a lot of export options, so this is a really good side effect. For example, you might want the root directory settings to be specific to each project, but want the object name prefix/suffix settings to be global.